# Same symbol name in multiple SO/DLL

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have a set of `lib*.so` libraries in which there's a symbol `uint64_t VERSION` defined. There are two ways these plug-in libraries are loaded, either via `dl_open()` or may be linked at compile time. Whichever way these plug-ins became visible in the main program, I'd like to execute some code based on the `VERSION` variable. For example, a simple version number printing for each of the libraries loaded.

Is it possible? If so, how?

I've been reading through `weak` linkages, but I don't know if this is suitable for my requirement or how to use it correctly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using `dlopen()`, you can retrieve a pointer to the symbol in the library via `dlsym()`, passing the library handle rather than a generic handle for the executable.  You can then access each separate `VERSION` variable via the pointers returned by `dlsym()`.  For example: `void *so_1 = dlopen(…); uint64_t *vp_1 = dlsym(so_1, "VERSION"); void *so_2 = dlopen(…); uint64_t *vp_2 = dlsym(so_2, "VERSION"); printf("V1 = %" PRIu64 ", V2 = %" PRIu64 "\n", *vp_1, *vp_2);`.

Comment: I'm almost certain there isn't an easy way to get at the different version number variables if the libraries a linked at compile time (rather than loaded via `dlopen()`).  The first `VERSION` in the libraries becomes 'the `VERSION`' for the program.  There might be intricate ways to find the other ones using `dlopen()` and some platform-specific black magic.

Comment: Is there a better way at doing this then? Getting the version number from any loaded plugin., whichever way they're loaded.